# Подсветка строк в Debug mode в VS2012

Tags: visual-studio

работаю на VS2012, и нужно периодически дебажить код(ну как не без этого), захожу в нужный мне брейкпойнт и строка начинает выделяться так, что мне трудно увидеть, что там написано, как можно изменить цвет подсветки, или вовсе убрать её?

пытался убирать галочки по путям :

> tools->options->text editor->highlight current line

а так же :

> tools->options->debug->highlight entire source line ...

Парочка скринов

"Code mode" :

[image: стало]

Debug :

[image: стало]

Comment: Это у вас ну очень странная цветовая схема. У меня 2008-я и 2015-я студии, таких проблем нет. Попробуйте дефолтную схему.

Comment: Это просто тип темы dark (очень удобная)

Comment: Была бы очень удобная - вопроса бы не было :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменить цвет подсветки можете в настройках:

> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors

Убрать подсветку можно установив цвет такой же как цвет заднего фона

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]